Is 3-Nitrooxypropanol explosive?
This appears to be the active ingredient in a food supplement for cattle designed to suppress methane production. It is named Bovaer®
Typically nitrated alcohols are not too stable. So, apart from cow farts, is this an explosive?

Meh, at a first glance doesn't seem much more explosive, than aforementioned farts ;)

But methane-air mix can explode and this thing is bound to be worse. OH makes b.p. higher, fortunately, and as a medicine, the doses should be small, even for cows.

being "explosive" isn't really a property of a molecule: it the property of a bulk substance. Ammonium nitrate in bulk is dangerously explosive (several thousand tons stored badly is what destroyed a large part of the port of Beirut). But mixed with soil across a field it is not explosive. Same here: bulk nitroxypropanol might be dangerous but it will be safe as a diluted ingredient in cattle feed.

@matt_black Well, this is produced in bulk and will be fed to cattle in quantity. I was wondering if the purified form could be (say) easily solvent extracted from the commercial offering and used for terrorist purposes.

@DirkBruere I think there are far better alternatives (like ammonium nitrate). nitrooxypropanol might not even be a good explosive (nitrated organics that are explosive tend to have far higher levels of nitration like TNT or nitroglycerine). And the warnings on the pure substance data sheets list flammability but not explosion hazard.

Consider that human beings take nitroglycerin (or  or 1,2,3-trinitroxypropane, should you prefer) for angina, without dying of a broken heart.

@DrMoishePippik But pharmacies do not stock it in kg quantities
